# sed in place deletion between patterns only first match

Tags: linux, regex, sed

I am looking to delete lines between two strings (including the two strings) only for the first occurence of the match, the same set of strings keep repeating in the file, I have tried using the below, but it does not seem to work :

```
sed -n -e '/prefix/,/agents/d' -e '/agents/$q' /var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2
```

Also , want to delete first occurrence in-place and not redirect to standard output so something using `-i`.

First 30 lines of my File looks like below :

```
 },{
   "prefix" : "AD",
   "prefix" : "CQ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 0,
   "month" : 5,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 0,
   "yesterday": 2,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "agents": 0
  },{
   "prefix" : "CS",
   "prefix" : "AE",
   "last" : 1,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 130,
   "month" : 0,
   "today": 0,
   "today": 20,
   "yesterday": 0,
   "yesterday": 38,
   "agents": 0
  },{
   "prefix" : "AF",
   "prefix" : "CZ",
   "last" : 0,
   "last" : 0,
   "month" : 6,
```

Regards,
Sriram.V

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I *think* this sed does what you want. Since the input file has some identical lines, I edited it adding "first block", "second block" and "third block". It seems that it worked `sed -n '/prefix/!p;/prefix/ {:a;N;s/agents/&/;tb;ba;:b;s/.*//;:c;n;p;${q};bc}'`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very difficult problem, because of the requirement to delete only the first instance.

For example this deletes *every* instance:

```
sed '/prefix/,/agents/d' /var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2
```

This deletes only the first instance, but does leaves the first and last lines:

```
sed -n -e '1,/prefix/p' -e'/agents/,$p' /var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2
```

I have tried to remove them within a single `sed` command, but I have not succeeded. The best I managed is to split into two files and then combine them:

```
sed -n '1,/prefix/p' </var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2|head -n -1 >head.tmp
sed -n '/agents/,$p' </var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2|tail -n +2 >tail.tmp
cat head.tmp tail.tmp >/var/saas/stats/usage_1499245200.json.2
rm head.tmp tail.tmp
```

(You don't need two separate files, but it is easier to understand when you use them.)

There may possibly be a single `sed` command using grouped commands and the holding buffer, but it will be mind-numbingly complex and almost impossible to support and modify.

If you want to have a go, look at [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html), but be prepared for your head to start spinning when you get on to the advanced sections.